# Can i get installed certificate on my system through java

Tags: java, security, digital-certificate

Can i get installed certificates on my system through java

something like this Eg. Certificate[] certificate = someClass.getsystemCertificates();

Is there is some api available for this????

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `keytool` command to get the list of certificates in your cacerts file, which is the collection of approved certificates that Java comes with.  The default password for this keystore is "changeit".

`keytool -list -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit`

Comment: Getting such error i am using Windows
keytool error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Usage error, Files/Java/jre/lib/security is not a legal command

Comment: There is a space in the path to your Java installation.  Put quotes around the keystore path: `-keystore "$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts"`

Comment: Sorry, not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the system. Windows has centralized certificate storage, while other platforms don't (at least, no uniform one). So querying system certificates is platform-specific. And as it is, it would be wise to look for JNI to platform-specific API for doing what you need.

I guess there must be some class already available for Windows (most likely working via JNI), but I never saw one. I'd be interested in such solution too (for specific purposes where JNI can't be used).