# How can I check if a windows digit certificate installed in a client windows system using java?

Tags: java, certificate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can i get installed certificate on my system through java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325535/can-i-get-installed-certificate-on-my-system-through-java)

Our web site let users to install a client x.509 digit certificate  in their windows client. we need to check if the users logining  our site install our digit certification successfully.
We decide to check this digit certificate using java applet, but not a available method is provided in google. How can i check if a digit certificate in installed in their windows client using java applet?

Comment: What is a 'digit certificate'?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you read certificates from from the windows certificate store:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY", "SunMSCAPI");
ks.load(null, null);

Enumeration<String> aliases = ks.aliases();

while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
    String alias = (String) aliases.nextElement();
    X509CertImpl certificate = (X509CertImpl)ks.getCertificate(alias);

    System.out.println("Alias: " + alias);
    System.out.println("  Subject: " + certificate.getSubjectDN());
    System.out.println("  Issued By: " + certificate.getIssuerDN());

    if (ks.isKeyEntry(alias)) {
        System.out.println("  Has private key");
    }
}
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunMSCAPI